# Is it possible to add opacity to the GoogleMap widget?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin

I'm attempting to add opacity to the `GoogleMap` widget but not seeing any changes.

I've previously tried wrapping the entire widget with a `Container` then adding `Opacity` and `GoogleMap` as direct children but this did not work either.

The code below builds correctly, but adds no opacity:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(
            opacity: 0.5,
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _center,
                zoom: 15.0,
              ),
              indoorViewEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              markers: _markers
            )
          ),
          ...
        ]
      )
    )
  );
}
```

I would expect the map to be opaque. Is this possible with GoogleMaps plugin or do they prevent styling like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`google_maps_flutter` plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) renders a native [`GMSMapView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view) on iOS and a native [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/MapView) on Android, so the alpha setting need to be implemented by the plugin itself to be able to access it.

Unfortunately you can't use Flutter's `Opacity` widget in the way you have attempted when rendering native components, since that widget only works on elements that are drawn on the canvas by Flutter itself.

So if you really want to achieve this, you'll have to implement this in Android and iOS yourself. In that case you can use the `google_maps_flutter` plugin as a reference.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, appreciate the response Tim.